# C# Ajax form processor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an AJAX contact form that will send an email when it is submitted.

I have never done any C# programming, but I have done lots of PHP.

This is the javascript I am using to do the AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/?????',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email, phone: phone, message: message},
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#submit-button").attr("disabled","disabled");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if ( data.email_status == "true" ) {
            var success_msg = "Your message has been sent.";

            // Email Sent

            // Reset form.
            $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
        } else if ( data.email_status == "false" ) {
            var error_msg = "There has been an error sending your message. Please try again later.";

            // Email not sent.
        }
    }
});
```

This is all on a .html file. It will be posted to a C# file and will need a JSON response.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is alot that needs to happen here. This is an example of how you would write the c# controller contents.

public void SendMessage(mailModels modelData){

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
mail.Subject = modelData.toString();
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
client.Send(mail);
```

}

You could basically need to structure a model in c# to pass your form data through. Then send the model data in the email subject.

There are many ways to do this. I prefer to break up the model data and create a structure to the email like:

```
var subject = "First Name : " + modelData.FirstName + "Last Name : " + modelData.LirstName;
```

Something like that. Are you actually trying to write the c# code in .NET etc? Or needing to know how to post to it?

Comment: I need to know how to handle the post data. I haven't got any C# code written yet. Posting to it should work fine. Can I just create a .aspx file and run this code in that, or does it need to run is a .cs file?

Comment: It would have to be done in a controller because you have to add references etc in .NET as far as I know. I only have experience in the .NET MVC realm

Comment: You have a couple of asp.net options.  The most simple would be to use asp.net [webpages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started).  Another option would be what @JudsonTerrell mentioned using which is an [mvc web application](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started).  If all you are needing is a simple single .net endpoint then you could consider using a web service type handler [HTTP handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675.aspx)